# How to keep a consistent identifier on an async method with Serilog

Tags: c#, logging, .net-core, serilog

Consider the following code:

```
public async Task DoStuff() {
  ILogger logger = LoggerFactory.CreateLogger<PuppetFactory>();
  logger.LogDebug("1");
  await Something()
  logger.LogDebug("2");
  await SomethingElse()
  logger.LogDebug("3");
}
```

In the `outputTemplate` for Serilog, I have `{ThreadId}`.  Of course, since async/await throws the code execution from thread to thread, my log shows different thread IDs.

What can I use in my output template to have the same identifier for this specific execution run?

Comment: Your program has a life cycle. Create a unique identifier to be used on life cycle a to z, this is the way we do it in my work space to track what happen. If you need more formal answer with example, let me know. and if I have misunderstand you let me know.

Comment: My understanding is that Serilog provides a unique identifier to the execution run, I just don't know what it is.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to invent and apply the identifier yourself, e.g. `OperationId`:

```
// .Enrich.FromLogContext(), then
using (LogContext.PushProperty("OperationId", 123))
{
    // Your async code here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the code is literally as above and you can pass the `logger` along, you can skip the normal `LogContext` / `Enrich.FromLogContext` as per Nick's answer and add a contextual property into its context, i.e.

```
var opLogger = logger.ForContext("OperationId",123);
```

then use `opLogger` where you want messages to be tagged - then either use `{OperationId}` specific property, or the catch-all `{Properties}` meta-token (which means "all properties not specifically mentioned elsewhere") to emit the value in your *message template* when rendering.